# NHibernate: many-to-one and lazy

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

There is something regarding NHibernate 1.2 (webapp C# aspnet 3.5) and lazy loading that I don't understand and I can't find some clear answer: does many-to-one support lazy loading?

Let's say we have some `Person` object and a `Squeletton` object. Both objects are big with many properties. A `Person` has one and only one `Squeletton`: myPerson.Squelleton.

Mapping of `Person`: `<many-to-one class='Squeletton' name='Squeletton' column='id_squeletton' lazy='proxy' />`

I don't want the `Squeletton` property to be loaded every time `Person` is. Using NHProfiler I can see "select" requests for `Squeletton` even if I don't access the property.

What is wrong: mapping? bad use of many-to-one? NHibernate version? How can I have some lazy loading on Squeletton property?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy loading is the default, but it should work fine with your mapping.

Are you 100% sure you are not accessing the property? Watching it in the debugger, maybe?

In any case, you should certainly update NHibernate to the last release, 3.2, as 1.2 is really outdated and has been unsupported for ages (as has 2.x)

Comment: I've cleared the debugger and set a breakpoint in my property, it isn't called. I am in the process of building a sample app, and I am not reproducing my issue... As you say, the mapping is ok for lazy loading. I'll be back after some tests.