# Hibernate 1-to-1 mapping column is not being set

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have 2 tables:

```
create table EMPLOYEE (
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   first_name VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   last_name  VARCHAR(20) default NULL,
   salary     INT  default NULL,
   address    INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table ADDRESS (
   id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   street_name VARCHAR(40) default NULL,
   city_name VARCHAR(40) default NULL,
   state_name VARCHAR(40) default NULL,
   zipcode VARCHAR(10) default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

where `EMPLOYEE.address` is a foreign key mapped to `ADDRESS`

My mapping file is defined as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="Employee" table="EMPLOYEE">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the employee detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="firstName" column="first_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="lastName" column="last_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="salary" column="salary" type="int"/>
      <many-to-one name="address" column="address" unique="true" 
       class="Address" not-null="true"/>
   </class>

   <class name="Address" table="ADDRESS">
      <meta attribute="class-description">
         This class contains the address detail. 
      </meta>
      <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
         <generator class="native"/>
      </id>
      <property name="street" column="street_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="city" column="city_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="state" column="state_name" type="string"/>
      <property name="zipcode" column="zipcode" type="string"/>
   </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

But, when I pull `Employee` objects all the normal fields are populated normally except the `Address` field in the `Employee` plain old object has all the values set to null.  What could be causing this?

Comment: have you created the fk constraint btween employee & address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unfortunately a bit long for a comment, but hopefully this will give you something to look at:*

It is my understanding that `NHibernate` is actually "lazy by default", this means that the `Address` object won't be populated until requested, and then (if I remember correctly) only if you are still connected. I've had issues in the past of passing partially loaded objects to a `view`  in my `MVC` projects and yours sounds similar.

That being said, I've read on several articles that you `NHibernate` doesn't lazy-load for `many-to-one` relationships, however I still think this is probably worth looking into. The `many-to-one` relationship requires the use of a foreign key, and therefore the referencing column must be the primary key. I.e. `EMPLOYEE.address = ADDRESS.id`.

Once you solve your problem please post what was actually wrong as I am looking to improve my knowledge in `NHibernate`.

You might find the following articles useful:

- [Solving Performance Problems with nHibernate (or any ORM)](http://geekswithblogs.net/Optikal/archive/2013/03/10/152371.aspx)

And these Questions:

- [NHibernate: many-to-one and lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969156/nhibernate-many-to-one-and-lazy)
- [NHibernate 1.x : many-to-one not lazily loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413832/nhibernate-1-x-many-to-one-not-lazily-loaded)

Comment: Amazing, you're right. I was looking at my objects in debug mode, but they are populated as soon as you actually use the mapped properties. Thanks for saving me from hours more of painful research.